# How to isolate $f(x)$ in $f(x+a)=f(x)+a\times g(x)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, tag-removed, special-functions

$a \in \mathbb{R}$

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

For generic functions $f$ and $g$, how isolate $f(x)$ in the equation below?

> $f(x+a)=f(x)+a\times g(x)$

I tried to use [Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)  but looks like this don't work very well.

$f(x - a)=$
$e^{-2\pi i a \xi} \hat{f}(\xi)$

$\hat{f}(\xi)=$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) e^{-2\pi i x\xi}\, dx \quad$
*(Fourier Transform)*

I tried [ZTransform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) too, but again, didn't worked very well.

Comment: Does your equation have to hold for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$? Most importantly, what do you mean by "isolate"? 

Comment: You are actually trying to calculate the indefinite sum of terms defined by $f$ (just look at the case $a=1$), so you really should narrow down the class of functions to have summation algorithms.

Comment: @Qfwfq, isolate is find `f` or $f(x)=\cdots$, where $\cdots$ is something using $g$ and $a$.

Comment: This should not have the special-functions tag

Comment: I think use DiracDelta is special functions no? And using Fourier Transforms, for example, DiracDelta appears frequently.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is not unique - you can add any function of period $a$ to f. This is what the singularities are trying to tell you. In a distributional sense, the Fourier transform of a function of period a is supported exactly on the zeros of $e^{2 \pi i a \xi}-1$.

Comment: @shrdlu Yes I agree, but if $f$ is unknown, how to find, at least, one solution to $f$?

Answer (score 5):

If you're not concerned with continuity, integrability, or any of the niceties of real analysis (and there's nothing in the problem that says you are), then, given $a\ne 0$ and $g$, you can let $f$ be *any* function on the interval $[0,|a|)$ and simply extend it to all real numbers by repeated applications of the given functional equation (written in the form $f(x) = f(x+a) - ag(x)$ to extend it in the direction opposite to the sign of $a$).  If $a=0$, it's clear $f$ can be anything.

Addition:  Let me be somewhat more explicit.  If $a=1$, we can let $f$ be identically zero on $[0,1)$ and equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{[x]} g(x-k)$ for $x\ge1$, with a similar formula for $x<0$.

Comment: Didn't understand very well. Can you give an example? For example, using $a=1$ ang $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x(x-1)}$ who mathematica don't solves.

Comment: @GarouDan: Barry Cipra's point is that not every function is of the nice form that Mathematica would give you - not every function is given by a formula. If you are only interested in functions that are "physically realistic" in some sense then you should probably make this clear in the question

Answer (score 4):

Just as you said:$e^{2\pi i a \xi} \hat{f}(\xi)= \hat{f}(\xi) +a \hat{g}(\xi)$. In this way you get $\hat{f}(\xi)$ and you can use it to find $f(x)$.

Comment: In Mathematica, if we try

$a=1$ and $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x(x+1)}$

$f(x)=a (\mathcal{F}_{\xi }^{-1}[\frac{\mathcal{F}_x[G(x)](\xi )}{-1+e^{2
   i \pi  a \xi }}])(x)$

We have no answer, but, is easy to know the answer.

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ because,

$f(x+1)=f(x)+1\times g(x) \iff \frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x}=g(x) \iff \frac{-1}{x(x+1)}=g(x)$

Comment: @GarouDan: Shall I write more details?


Comment: I don't know what's wrong with mathematica, my answer is clear.


Comment: If you have Mathematica you can try:

a=1

G[x]=1/(x*(x-1))

F[y_]:=InverseFourierTransform[a*FourierTransform[G[x],x,k]/(E^(2*Pi*I*k*a)-1),k,y]

and finally

F[y] to see the results...but your kernel probably will works forever>

So my new question is, Fourier and InverseFourier transforms can't solve this simple question?

Comment: Mathematica may not like the fact that the function you are taking the inverse transform of has singularities at $a\xi\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Do the singularities at $a\xi$ mean that the solution is wrong?


Comment: I don't think so. You just need to take some care with the integral, say by shifting the contour. I can't guarantee that this works out, but this sort of thing happens when you want to solve differential equations via Fourier inversion: you end up wanting to take the inverse transform of $1/P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is some polynomial that may have poles on the real line.

Comment: I was going to say "unfortunately I don't know a good source for this, as I learnt it from Folland's excellent Lectures on Partial Differential Equations, which is very hard to find nowadays", but I see that the Tata Institute has made it available online (and re-typeset)! http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr70.pdf

Comment: @BR: Thank you for the comments and the link! 

Comment: I mean, what the poles are expressing is that you only know $f$ up to a periodic function with period $a$. It's up to you to coax a reasonable closed form out of it, and Fourier shouldn't work in general. In fact, nothing should.

Comment: @AliBleybel I can't embrace you answer as solution how it presents now. When I put the FourierTransform link and that formulas, I tried it before. I tried isolate $f(x)$ using that. And tried using [ZTransform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) too. It's not a easy question. Maybe we can use ZTransform to several things and FourierTransform to many others and other transform and find all solutions. Don't know, but if $a=1$ or $a\implies 0$, I think there limitated solutions. And I'm searching a way to find them.

Comment: @BR , Are you saying it's possible find $f(x)$ in my exampling using Inverse Fourier Transform, but Mathematica, don't do it?

Comment: GarouDan, the inverse Fourier transform (maybe with a shifted contour) defines a solution to your problem. As Will Sawin points out, this usually won't have a closed-form expression.